# What is a good way to create a bias while generating random numbers?

Tags: algorithm, random, distribution, probability, weighted

Say if you have a 2 identical arrays of n elements say with numbers from 1 to 10. You randomly pick an item from each array and check if they match. For one iteration the right match can be (10,10) or (3,3) as it randomly changes every time. Since both the arrays have 10 elements, getting the right match overall is very infrequent, if you pick a random number from each array. So each time, a specific weight can be assigned to the right match to increase this frequency. My question is how much weight do you assign the right match so it is more frequent but still seems random enough? How do you decide this?

Comment: That's like asking "how long is tall". The weight you use depends entirely on what you need the results for.

Comment: Crossposted: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97901/assigining-weights-to-numbers-before-random-number-generation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem domain is, but this kind of thing is a pretty common game design problem, and the solution pretty much comes down to trial-and-error. Implement a weighting that you think makes sense, and then run a bunch of user tests to see what people think of it. Adjust according to your results, and then test again. Ultimately, the "correct" weights are going to depend on your use case, your users, how you feel, etc; there's no one right answer.

Incidentally, many game developers approach this situation with an algorithm referred to as [shuffle bag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29743/how-do-i-produce-enjoyably-random-as-opposed-to-pseudo-random). This way you can avoid long strings of successes or failures; while true randomness has such strings sometimes, people generally don't like that. Instead, a shuffle bag is when you fill the "bag" with all the desired results in the desired distribution, and then randomly pull results from the bag. This way the pulls are still random, but you're not going to get long strings of rare events.